# Get an image from an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to place an image from an array into a div.

```
arralegro =[ "01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png"];

n=2;
var goImg = 'alegro/' + arralegro[n];
alert (goImg); //correct - `alegro/02.png`
$('#divR').empty();
$("#divR").prepend('<img id="slide" src=' + goImg + '/>'); // here is something wrong
```

Firebug says - `404 Not Found`. But the image is there.

```
$("#divR").prepend('<img id="slide" src="alegro/02.png"/>');  // works this way
```

Comment: did you try different versions of the url...for example.../alegro/+ or http://www.test.com/alegro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be forgetting the double quotes around the src attribute. Try this line:

```
$("#divR").prepend('<img id="slide" src="' + goImg + '" />'); // here is something wrong
```

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the quotes:

```
$("#divR").prepend('<img id="slide" src="' + goImg + '"/>');
```